# WP-TweetButton is not displaying the tweet button if this is set to "Manual."

Tags: plugins, twitter

I'm using the [WP-TweetButton](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-tweetbutton/) but when I set the settings to add the button manually. Nothing is displayed.

Settings:[image]

The Code:

```
    <div id="social-buttons">
                        <div id="tweet-button">
                            <?php tweetbutton(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="fb-share"><?php if (function_exists('fbshare_manual')) echo fbshare_manual(); ?></div>
                        <div id=fb-like><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:60px"></iframe></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'next &rarr;', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

I'm using Wordpress 3.1.2 and the last version of the plugin.

Is anyone having this problem too? Have anyone managed to fix it?

Comment: why did I get down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally, got it;

`<?php echo tweetbutton(); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've mis-named the function. It is `the_tweetbutton()`, rather than `tweetbutton()`.

Also, you should *always* wrap Plugin-added function calls in `if (function_exists())` conditional wrappers.

Putting that together, this:

```
<div id="tweet-button">
      <?php tweetbutton(); ?>
</div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div id="tweet-button">
      <?php if ( function_exists( 'the_tweetbutton' ) ) the_tweetbutton(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Chip Bennet Thanks! So the official documentation is wrong: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-tweet-button/. `Supports automatic placement and manual using tweetbutton();`

Comment: Apparently so, I guess. I just looked at the Plugin's PHP file in trunk. :)  (What do the instructions say on the Plugin Settings page?)

Comment: @Chip Bennett There's nothing. Well, I will try the function you suggested when I come back home. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, well I was looking at trunk. Maybe the documentation has been improved since the last-tagged version?

Comment: @Chip Bennett Weird. I tried that but still no luck.

Comment: @Chip Bennet `Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_tweetbutton() in /home/aleche23/alexchen.info/nojokethistime/wp-content/themes/prominent/front-page.php on line 25`